# LINQ TO SQL TRANSACTIONSCOPE ERROR

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am getting an error on TransactionScope() and datacontext as below.

The type or namespace name 'TransactioScope' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The type or namespace name 'HRPaidTimeOffDataContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What must I do to fix this issue in the code below.

```
using ( TransactioScope ts = new TransactionScope())
         {
            // Create the data context
            using (HRPaidTimeOffDataContext db = new HRPaidTimeOffDataContext())
            {
            //Now save the record
            if (this.Save(db, ref validationErrors, userAccountId))
            {
            // Commit transaction if update was successful
            ts.Complete();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
        return false;
        }
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Yes, you are missing that. Two actually...

The first: TransactionScope.

In the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) you wil find:

> Namespace:  System.Transactions
>
> Assembly:  System.Transactions (in
>   System.Transactions.dll)

So you need to include this line in the top of your code:

```
using System.Transactions;
```

The other one is one of your own

```
HRPaidTimeOffDataContext
```

So I cannot tell you what to type, but I guess you will manage by now.

Comment: I was missing a reference in my project to system.Transactions. After adding this reference and adding using system.transactions directive on top, the error disappered thank you for your eye opening.